# DOM style attributes don't want to set under Javascript

Tags: javascript, dom, attributes, styles

I've run into this a number of times, and up until now I've solved it with a hack. I'm tired of doing that. In short, I try to set a style attribute with Javascript, and the DOM tells me where to shove it. Case in point:

```js
function resizeTextRelative(elements, refelem){  
    let ref = document.getElementById(refelem);
    let height = refelem.getBoundingClientRect().height;
    elements.forEach(function(item, index) {
        let fs = parseInt(height*elements[index].ratio)+'px'; 
        item.elem.style.fontSize = fs;
     });  
}
```

The objective is to size a text field to something proportional to a reference element. In this case, the reference is a DIV, at initialization 141px high. It correctly calculates the new fontSize, but when it gets to actual style assignment, it goes nuts. We note the following:

1. item.elem is the correct DOM element, a DIV.
2. Its style.fontSize at this point is is '300%' the default value at startup.
3. fs holds the correct value of '14px'.

After the assignment:

1. fs is still '14px'.
2. item.elem.style.fontSize is now '', an empty string which resolves to 0.

Naturally, the DIV disappears from view. 0≠'14px'. Does anyone have an idea what is going on here? As usually, my attempt to search for an answer returns dozens of irrelevant results.

I don't know what else to try. I've set style attributes this way hundreds of times, and almost always it works.  What did I expect to happen? Naturally, I expected item.elem.style.fontSize to be set to '14px'.

Here is the calling code if anyone needs it. Browser is Firefox Developer 99.0b8.

```
var header_text = [ { elem: document.getElementById('vision-text'), ratio: 0.1, x: 0.5, y: 0.35 },
    { elem: document.getElementById('duane-text'),  ratio: 0.2, x: 0.5, y: 0.65 } ];
    const headerResizeObserver = new ResizeObserver(function(entries){
    let hdr = document.getElementById('header');
        resizeTextRelative(header_text, hdr);
        positionElementsRelative(header_text, hdr);
        });
    headerResizeObserver.observe(document.getElementById('header'));
```

Comment: What type is `elements` ? If it's an HTMLElement collection, shouldn't you assign the element style like this:`item.style.fontSize=fs` instead of : `item.elem.style.fontSize` ?

Comment: It's an array of objects, with the format: { 
   elem: HTMLelement,
   ratio: size ratio,
   x: x position,
   y: y position }, not an HTMLElement collection. x and y are used elsewhere. But I've seen this same behavior in other circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

i dont think the 'document.getElementById()' works like that anyways with something like that i have no problems doing what you want to do:

```
function resizeTextRelative(elements, refelem){    
  let height = refelem.getBoundingClientRect().height;

  elements.forEach(function(item, index) {

    // get the element by selector
    let htmlElement = document.querySelector(item.selector);
  
    let fs = parseInt(height*elements[index].ratio)+'px';
    htmlElement.style.fontSize = fs;

  });


}

header_text = [ 
  { selector: '#vision-text', ratio: 0.4, x: 0.5, y: 0.35 }, 
  { selector: '#duane-text', ratio: 0.2, x: 0.5, y: 0.65 } 
]; 

let hdr = document.getElementById('header'); 
resizeTextRelative(header_text, hdr);
```

Comment: David, your way didn't work either, but tinkering some more, I found that it does work when called directly from the main code, but not when invoked by the observer. I can't fathom what difference that would make. Anyone have thoughts on that?

Comment: More info: when called from the observer, it generates a warning:
Ignoring get or set of property that has [LenientThis] because the “this” object is incorrect.
There is some chatter about this online, but I'm burned out on it right now. I can see why the "this" could be "wrong", but I don't see where it should care.

Comment: i dont see why it should not work, look at my Codepen if its not working for you then there are some other parts you didn't mention:
[link]https://codepen.io/davidbroedner/pen/zYpRdqZ
just resize the browser and you can see the font-size changes with the element height.

Comment: Found it! My mind was terribly boggled because except for names, my code was identical to yours, so it had to be elsewhere. It was in the HTML. The name DIVs were relative positioned children of the DIV I was monitoring, and although the observed DIV wasn't supposed to be changing size, I guess it was, and it called the handler recursively until the size dwindled to zero. Now I need to figure out why the outer DIV was changing size when it shouldn't have been. Thanks for the help.